# Save .dta files in python

Tags: python, numpy, stata

I'm wondering if anyone knows a Python package that allows you to save numpy arrays/recarrays in the `.dta` format of the statistical data analysis software Stata. This would really speed up a few steps in a system I have.

Comment: What exactly is an .dta file supposed to be?

Comment: A .dta file is a file format associated with data, primarily used for the statistical computing program STATA.  I don't know enough about file type to elaborate, but there might be more detail here: http://filext.com/file-extension/DTA

Comment: You seem to have the misconception that all files having the extension `.dta` have a common format.  This is not true.  The file format you are interested in is specific to STATA and doesn't seem to be used in any other software.  Here is the [documentation of the format](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dta), and I very much doubt there exists a library being able to write this format.

Comment: Probably you can use STATA's [infile command](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?infile1) to import a CSV file generated with Python.

Comment: I am able to use infile/insheet commands to bring in .csv files to STATA, but .dta files can be appended (ie,stacked) many-fold faster than the process of bringing in .csvs, saving them, bringing in other .csvs (it's a rather inefficient program, but is necessary for my team's research).

Comment: If you are concerned about efficiency and speed, you could work with a relational database. Write the python arrays into a database and access it with Stata's `odbc`command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) DataFrame objects now have a "to_stata" method. So you can do for instance

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_stata('my_data_in.dta')
df.to_stata('my_data_out.dta')
```

**DISCLAIMER:** the first step is quite slow (in my test, around 1 minute for reading a 51 MB dta - also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744527/pandas-read-stata-with-large-dta-files)), and the second produces a file which can be way larger than the original one (in my test, the size goes from 51 MB to 111MB). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297044/2858145) may look less elegant, but it is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

The [scikits.statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) package includes a reader for Stata data files, which relies in part on PyDTA as pointed out by @Sven. In particular, `genfromdta()` will return an `ndarray`, e.g.
from Python 2.7/statsmodels 0.3.1:

```
>>> import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
>>> arr = sm.iolib.genfromdta('/Applications/Stata12/auto.dta')
>>> type(arr)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The `savetxt()` function can be used in turn to save an array as a text file, which can be imported in Stata. For example, we can export the above as

```
>>> sm.iolib.savetxt('auto.txt', arr, fmt='%2s', delimiter=",")
```

and read it in Stata without a dictionary file as follows:

```
. insheet using auto.txt, clear
```

I believe a `*.dta` reader should be added in the near future.

Answer (score 7):

The only [Python library for STATA interoperability](http://presbrey.mit.edu/PyDTA) I could find merely provides read-only access to `.dta` files.  The R `foreign` library however provides a function [`write.dta`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/write.dta.html), and [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) provides a Python interface to R.  Maybe the combination of these tools can help you.