# most efficient I/O setup between Stata and Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, io, stata

I am using Stata to process some data, export the data in a csv file and load it in Python using the pandas read_csv function.

The problem is that everything is so slow. Exporting from Stata to a csv file takes ages (exporting in the dta Stata format is much faster), and loading the data via read_csv is also very slow. Using the read_stata pandas function is even worse.

I wonder is there are any other options? Like exporting a format other than csv? My csv dataset is approx 6-7 Gb large.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `read_stata()` is much faster starting with version 15.0 of pandas, so make sure you are up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty efficient `pd.read_stata()/.to_stata()`, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#stata-format)

Comment: Thanks jeff but it appears that loading stata large datasets in pandas is even slower than using csv...

Comment: @Noobie make sure you are using pandas 15.0 or higher which is much faster at reading DTA files than version 14 and earlier.  That said, I have had some problems with larger stata datasets.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748088/overflow-error-with-pandas-read-stata

Comment: you can use ``chunksize=..`` option as of 0.16.0. should be quite efficient

Comment: Good point, I did still have that same problem with version 16 but didn't try the chunksize option.