# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long - while loading Stata dta in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I am using the following code (see here [Pandas read_stata() with large .dta files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744527/pandas-read-stata-with-large-dta-files)) to load a very large Stata dataset (20GB) in Python. My machine has 128 GB RAM.

```
def load_large_dta(fname):
   import sys

    reader = pd.read_stata(fname, iterator=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    try:
        chunk = reader.get_chunk(100*1000)
        while len(chunk) > 0:
            df = df.append(chunk, ignore_index=True)
            chunk = reader.get_chunk(100*1000)
            print '.',
            sys.stdout.flush()
    except (StopIteration, KeyboardInterrupt):
        pass

    print '\nloaded {} rows'.format(len(df))

   return df
```

Problem is: I get the following error:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @AbrahamDFlaxman , creator of this nice iterator, I summon you! ;-)

Comment: just a heads up, the '@user' notification only works if the user has participated in this post.  This this [meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) question for more info

Comment: oh ok thanks! does that mean there is no way to attract someone's attention in a comment?

Comment: Only if they've been here before

Comment: Aside: that code is very inefficient.  `append` has to make a new copy of the entire frame, and so very soon you'll spend more time doing the append over and over again than the reading.  If you really want a chunked read, store the chunks and then concatenate them.

Comment: @DSM thank you for your input. I am learning Pandas as we speak. Can you please show me how you would read the chunks as you suggest? Thanks!!!

Comment: Basically `chunks = []; while len(chunk) > 0: chunks.append(reader.get_chunk(...)); df = pd.concat(chunks)`.

Comment: @filmor please post a complete snippet so that I can accept your answer

Comment: I don't know whether it fixes your error (post a more complete traceback), it's just an explanation how to do chunking in pandas without using `append`.